# Linq expression with nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to query an entity with a nullable DateTime, for example, select all Cars built in 2005:

```
public class Car() {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime? DateBuilt {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

My Linq-expression would normally look something like this:

```
int carsIn2005 = context.Cars.Count(x => x.DateBuilt.Year == "2005");
```

But I cannot use `.Year` because the Date is nullable. I've googled a bit, found something about the coalescing-operator, but could not make something usefull from that. Cool would be if Linq understood the following:

```
int carsIn2005 = context.Cars.Count(x => x.DateBuilt.HasValue && x.DateBuilt.Year == "2005");
```

If DateBuilt != null then I should be able to treat it as a DateTime.

Comment: How about `x.DateBuilt != null && x.DateBuilt.Year == 2005`?

Comment: @DavidG: Well, `x.DateBuilt != null && x.DateBuilt.Value.Year == 2005`

Comment: Note that even if `DateBuilt` weren't nullable, you couldn't compare an `int` with a `string`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Always one step ahead :)

Comment: Or in C# 6: `x.DateBuilt?.Year == 2005`

Comment: Cool ;o) Thank you Jon Skeet, the .Value did it!

Comment: (x.DateBuilt??DateTime.MinValue).Year==2005

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int carsIn2005 = context.Cars.Count(x => x.DateBuilt != null && x.DateBuilt.Value.Year == 2005);
```