# Comparing Datetime? inside Linq Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

i am trying to return queries from a DB using Entity Framework and Linq on a Nullable DateTime field.

I have the following code;

```
DateTime? from = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
DateTime? to = from.Value.AddMonths(1);

return context.Where<Job>(
          x => 
          x.NextDueDate?.Date >= from?.Date &&
          x.NextDueDate?.Date <= to?.Date).ToList();
```

Where Job is (reduced for brevity);

```
public class Job : AuditableEntity
{
    ...
    public DateTime? NextDueDate { get; set; }
```

I tried this from the following stack link;

[Linq expression with nullable DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432494/linq-expression-with-nullable-datetime)

However, when I try this I am getting the following error;

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Can anyone explain a solution to this please?

Comment: What is `context`? Is it something like `IEnumerable<Job>`?

Comment: The context used is an Entity Framework Context, so yes DbSet<Job>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the exception message said you cannot use `?`.

```
// First day of a month. E.g. 2/1/2018 12:00:00 AM
DateTime from = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

// Last day of a month and end of that day. E.g. 2/28/2018 11:59:59 PM
DateTime to = from.AddMonths(1).AddTicks(-1); 

return context.Where<Job>(
    x =>
        x.NextDueDate != null &&
        x.NextDueDate >= from &&
        x.NextDueDate <= to).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried this (which compiles), but then throws the eception >System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Nullable`1<System.DateTime> CCS.Core.Job.get_NextDueDate()'.

Comment: Thank Win, this was my original code. Its still throwing the above mentioned error with this. I have tried to just reduce it to x => x.NextDueDate != null but this too throws an error. Could there possibly be an issue deeper down in the EF? as it looks like its thinking next due date doesnt exist?

Comment: Did you check my last updated code? Above code should not throw any exception.

Comment: Yes I did thank you, this too threw the same error. Turned out it seems the binaries had not updated along for some reason. I deleted all the local DLL, cleaned and rebuilt and it worked like a charm. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting  public DateTime? NextDueDate { get; set; }. So the default value won't be null.

Please try below code, because the date time value won't be null in code even when you fetch the null date time column from db. Which have a default value equal to  1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
DateTime to = from.Value.AddMonths(1);
DateTime dateTimeDefault = default(DateTime);

return context.Where<Job>(
          x =>  
          x.NextDueDate.Date != dateTimeDefault
          x.NextDueDate.Date >= from.Date &&
          x.NextDueDate.Date <= to.Date).ToList();
```